# OracleConnectionStringBuilder Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle11g

I am using Oracle.DataAccess.Client to access to the database. It works fine all the time, then all of a sudden, I will

> The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnectionStringBuilder' threw an exception.
>   Inner exception: Configuration system failed to initialize

from this line of command

> OracleConnectionStringBuilder strBuilder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/914291/114029

Comment: Thanks, I will take note on that in future.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi its different case, i have everything installed properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It is because I am using userSettings previously then I switch to applicationSettings. Thus, i need to delete the user.config file that was previously generated by my application and everything back to normal now.

For those who are having the similar problem, the user.config can be found in C:\Users\[userName]\AppData\Local\Technology\[programName]